# What should be do after submit topology?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, topology

I'm new to storm I submitted topology but I want to shutdown storm.

First I killed topology by `bin/storm kill topology_name`

I want to close `zookeeper`, `nimbus`, `supervisor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you ran it terminal without supervisor, just close terminal.
if you ran it under supervisor,
   to stop zookeeper run "service zookeeper stop"
   to stop supervisor run "service supervisord stop"
   when supervisor shutdown, your storm will also shutdown

Answer (score 0):

You can just `kill` the processes.

You can figure out the process ID with `ps` command:

```
ps -ef
```

Look for a java process that shows `backtype.storm.ui.core` (Nimbus) and `backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor` in its command line arguments?

For Zookeeper, you can just call `bin/zkServer.sh stop`.

Comment: kill nimbus and supervisor how ? by closing tabs only ? and zookeeper how can i close it ?

Comment: Just extended my answer. Not sure what you mean by "closing tabs" though.

Comment: I mean i'm using terminal in Ubuntu so I opening tabs in terminal. Nimbus has own tab and supervisor has own tab so when I want to close nimbus I'll close tab of it then message will appear that this process will be killed   this way right or not ?

Comment: That would work. You can also hit `Ctrl+C` to kill the process before closing the terminal window.

Comment: Thanks for help and this for restart nimbus too ? i mean not to shutdown it only

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but if you start Nimbus and kill it via `Ctrl+C`, you can of course start Nimbus again as you did in the first place.

Comment: i mean for restart supervisor or nimbus there is the only way to restart it .. press ctrl+c then start it again

Comment: Yes. That is the only way.